# Skipping last 4 rows and the first 16 rows when reading excel file into Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I know how to skip the first 16 rows of a excel file when reading into Pandas like

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl', skiprows=16, usecols = "B:F")
```

But how can I skip the last 4 rows and the first 16 rows?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use also the `skipfooter` parameter, as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl', skiprows=16, skipfooter=4, usecols = "B:F")
```

> **skipfooter**   int, default 0
> Rows at the end to skip (0-indexed).